# Feeding supplementary sequence to LSTM/dynamic_rnn in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I have a network that takes in a sequence of one-hot-encoded observations and feeds it into an LSTM in batches and sequences of pre-determined length.

I am trying to introduce a modification, whereby along with feeding the sequences of actual observations, I could also feed a 'supplementary' sequence, which would reflect something about each corresponding observation in the sequence. For example, if I feed a sequence of [1,2,3,4,5], I'd also like to feed another sequence of say [0,0,1,0,0] to indicate that '3' in the original sequence has a certain property, while others don't.

Following someone's suggestion, I am trying to concatenate the one-hot-encoded original sequence with this supplementary sequence (which I call the 'mode') but while this runs OK, all I seem to be achieving ultimately is adding an extra element to the one-hot vectors, which become not-so one-hot anymore)

I have reduced the experimental code to the following minimum:

```
BATCH = 2
SEQ = 3
VOCAB = 5
CELL_SIZE = 4

X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [BATCH, SEQ])
X_hot = tf.one_hot(X, VOCAB, 1.0, 0.0)
X_mode = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [BATCH, SEQ])
X_mode_exp = tf.expand_dims(X_mode, axis=2)
X_tuple = tf.concat([X_hot, X_mode_exp], axis=2)

Hin = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [BATCH, CELL_SIZE])

cell = rnn.GRUCell(CELL_SIZE)
Y, H = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X_tuple, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    gInit = tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    h = np.zeros([BATCH, CELL_SIZE])
    x = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]])
    x_mode = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,1]])
    x_h_out, x_tuple_out, hout = sess.run([X_hot, X_tuple, H], feed_dict={X:x, X_mode: x_mode, Hin: h})
    print('x_hot:\n{}\n'.format(x_h_out))
    print('x_tuple:\n{}'.format(x_tuple_out))
```

Which produces the following output:

```
x_hot:
[[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]]

x_tuple:
[[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]]
```

What could be a better alternative approach to achieving this? Once again, what I'm after is feeding a line of 'additional information' into the LSTM which would reflect some additional information about each element in the sequence.

Comment: Why is this approach bad? You're passing the extra information as an additional input to the network, seems like the only logical thing to do.

Comment: I don't know if it's bad necessarily. I'm just concerned that what is normally supposed to be a 'one-hot' vector is not one-hot any more, it's essentially 'two-hot'. Are the optimizer and the accuracy evaluation operation down road going to  interpret properly what this means? For example tf.argmax() would return 0 for something like this: [1,0,0,1]. So what's the use of the last 1 in that vector?

Comment: No one said neural network inputs have to be a one-hot vector. For the calculations the vector is just a vector of numbers, and it'll eventually learn the proper interpretation of each neuron.